# How do I create a threshold of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, threshold

It is my understanding that thresholding is a step function meaning that pixel values are rounded off at each step. E.g. pixel value 33 would be rounded to 32(assuming there's a threshold of 32). In my code i am trying to accomplish thresholding but I don't think i am acheieving it. Can someone guide me as to what i am missing?

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

 img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread("abby.jpg"))

img = np.uint8((0.2126* img[:,:,0]) + \
np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))

threshold = 128

for row in img:  ## trying to loop through to find if each image pixel > threshold
   for col in row:
      if col > threshold:
        col = threshold
      else:
        col = 0

plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing the threshold value to the image file but to a local variable c. To read and write to a numpy array, please read the official docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index).

Try below code:-

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = np.uint8(mpimg.imread("abby.jpg"))

img = np.uint8((0.2126* img[:,:,0]) + \
np.uint8(0.7152 * img[:,:,1]) +\
np.uint8(0.0722 * img[:,:,2]))

threshold = 64

it = np.nditer(img, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['writeonly'])
while not it.finished:
    if it[0] > threshold:
        it[0] = threshold
    else:
        it[0] = 0
    it.iternext()

im = Image.fromarray(img)
im.save("output.jpeg")
plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

**Output Image**

[image: Output]

**Note**: Beware of how matplotlib is displaying the output image. It displays the intensity 64 with pure white color, which is incorrect representation.

Comment: Do read comment discussion between K.Sarkar and me for simpler code. Thanks to his expertise in python.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `for` loop. May be you are doing mistake by iteration using for loop.

```
if col > threshold:
        col = threshold
```

this **threshold** should be 255, that is the concept of threshold.

Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily, thresholding can be done in multiple ways, and setting to 255 is one way. Also, the issue here is the thresholded value is written to local variables and not to image memory.

Comment: For that case only 1 line code is sufficient for that: img[img<threshold]=0;.where img is the image array and you should have numpy

Comment: Yes, this will work, however will need two iterations: `img[img<threshold] = 0; img[img>threshold] = threshold;`. I am not so good in python, but it might be possible to convert this to a single iteration by merging index filtering of both commands.